# ATG - Override method and return more specific component

Tags: java, atg

I'm trying override some method to let it with more specific return. So I did.

```java
@Override
public StoreProfile getProfile() {
    return (StoreProfile)super.getProfile();
}
```

However, the method `super.getProfile()` always return null when it is overrided.

My enviroment has the following specifications.

```
.\java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b50)
Dynamic Code Evolution Client VM (build 0.2-b02-internal, 19.0-b04-internal, mixed mode)
```

## **Edited**

With some more tests I discovered this problem isn't a Java issue.
My project use ATG 10.0.3, and that problem happens when I try override some method that return a *component* (and just components) and cast it for a more specific class.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Do you get a non-null value if you do not overwrite the method?

Comment: @StefanWarminski yes, if I not override the method the return is non-null

Comment: Wouldn't it return whatever method `getProfile()` of parent class returns since `super` is called? What does `getProfile()` of parent return?

Comment: You need to attach more of your code to let us have some context. It sounds like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing an example of the Covariant Return problem, explained well here: https://dzone.com/articles/covariant-return-type-abyssal

The difference you are seeing with plain Java is that ATG is using JavaBeans. If JavaBeans loads the base class first, it sees both a get and set methods. If JavaBeans loads the subclass first, it sees a getter but no corresponding setter (it doesn't match on type, and it's not in the spec to check baseclasses). Because of this dependency, small changes in your server start-up can cause nulls, and you should always avoid this problem.

The best solution is to make your subclass's getter have a different name. Based on your example, I would use:

```java
public StoreProfile getStoreProfile() {
    return (StoreProfile) getProfile();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing something wrong. Consider this example:

```
public class SpecificSubclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Number number = parent.getNumber();
        Integer integer = (Integer) number;
        System.out.println(integer);

        A a = new A();
        integer = a.getNumber();
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

    static class Parent {

        public Number getNumber() {
            return new Integer(1);
        }
    }

    static class A extends Parent {

        @Override
        public Integer getNumber() {
            return (Integer) super.getNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1
1
```

The more specific `getNumber()` method of class A returns an `Integer`, otherwise the assignment

```
integer=a.getNumber();
```

would not work. And the output is '1', not null. Thus, the general case of returning a more specific subclass in an overridden method by calling super and casting works properly (assuming what the superclass method returns is indeed an instance of the more specific subclass).

Comment: I was making a more complete example as you did and it worked. Now I am sure it is not a Java problem, maybe is the problem of ATG Component (Oracle Commerce)